# A string representation of the properties and methods

Tags: c#, .net

How can implement this getter and setter? will it work with the methods instead of properties? or is it impossible to?

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
int x = someObject.GetProperty("X");
someObject.SetProperty("Y","Value");
someObject.Call("DoSomething");


class SomeClass
{
    public int X{ get; set; }
    public string Y{ get ;set; }
    public void DoSomething() { return; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for this sort of thing - for example:

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();

int x = someObject.GetType().GetProperty ("X").GetGetMethod ().Invoke (someObject,null);

somObject.GetType().GetProperty("Y").GetSetMethod().Invoke(someObject, new object[] { "Value" });

someObject.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething").Invoke(someObject, null);
```

Comment: what about methods with some arguments?

Comment: click on the link (Reflection) in my answer, there you will find several samples including "methods with parameters"...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use reflection:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
Type scType = sc.GetType();
PropertyInfo xProp = scType.GetProperty("X");
xProp.SetValue(sc, 7, null); // sets sc.X = 7
```